# PHP script update record in the DB when the script has been running for over 30 mins

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a PHP script which runs each night to update records in my DB.
In my DB I also have a record for this script:

**Filename**

script1.php

**completed**

N

Once the script completes I make one last update to the DB and this is to update 'script1.php' and change it to 'Y'

If I remove everything in the file besides the last call to the DB then the script changes the 'N' to a 'Y' just fine.

The problem is that before marking as complete I am getting records and inserting them into my DB which takes 38 minutes in total.

This is probably my issue , after 38 mins the script finishes however it doesnt update the 'N' to a 'Y'.

**code**

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
max_input_vars = 10000
memory_limit = 512M
max_execution_time = 3000
```

These are the config settings on the server , I cannot change these as these are already the max settings im allowed.

Although I get a 504 gateway timeout the records continue to insert into the DB. All the records are inserted perfectly however this 'N' isnt changes to a 'Y'.

How do I get the script to run long enough to update this 'N' to a 'Y' ?

**CODE as requested**

```
<?php
// Run Script
require_once('removed');

ignore_user_abort(true); // just to be safe

echo('Script Started.');

flush();
// Do processing here

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('removed');
require('removed');
require('remvoed');

$filename = basename(__FILE__);
checkcrondependencies($filename);


//REMOVED DATA SUPPLIER CLASS

  date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");


    $domainpath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    $inipath = REMOVED;
    $privatepath = REMOVED;

    $connection_settings = REMOVED;
    $dbhost = $connection_settings['dbhost'];
    $dbname = $connection_settings['dbname'];
    $dbuser = $connection_settings['dbuser'];
    $dbpass = $connection_settings['dbpass'];

    //Make connection to supplier 


   $iscronfile = 'Y';

  $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
  if (!$conn) {
      new_log_entry($filename,'DB Connection Failed','Y',$iscronfile);
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

    // pull data from supplier 
    //push data to DB
    // Total time 38 minutes

     echo "completed";
     setcroncompleted($filename); // <<< THIS IS SUPPOSED TO CHANGE 'N' TO A 'Y'
     new_log_entry($filename,'Run Time End:'.date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"),'N',$iscronfile);
```

Comment: after you changed your max_execution_time did you restart your apache server

Comment: Yes the server was restarted.

Comment: Can you put your code

Comment: I have added the code but it includes sensitive information that I had to remove unfortunately. All the smaller files that take only a few minutes to run have no issues updating the 'N' to a 'Y' however this file fails to update this.

Answer (score 0):

Script runs via cron? Make some limiter to limit script execution. 
You can make cron to fire a hour each minute but log somewhere that $script_is_busy == true and update_is_done = false. After limiter hits limit make sure $script_is_busy = false and log how far updates was made. After one minute the next cron iteration will continue updates. When update is done log $update_is_done = true;.
It not big deal if cron fires "empty scipt" like if unpdate_is_dome == true ? die().

Comment: Script doesnt update the 'N' to a 'Y' even when fired manually. The whole file runs perfectly besides updating the 'N' to a 'Y' . I have no clue how all the other records go into the DB but this last change is ignored.

Comment: does it log new_log_entry?

Comment: No it doesn't log either

Comment: Just figure out how to properly run script more than one time. for example 2*20min or 4*10min.

Comment: That's not  the answer to this though. I know I can split this file into multiple smaller ones and it will run but It would be better for me to find out the answer to why this file refuses to update to the DB after it has been running for 30 mins

Comment: But the max execution time is 3000 that's 50 minutes? So in theory 38 mins should be fine .

Comment: Naa... I don't believe that. Something somewhere overrides it.

Comment: I just tried to run the file and instead of updating the db by passing the filename to the required file I manually entered a statement into the bottom of the file to update the DB. This has fixed the issue and the 'N' updated to a 'Y' successfully. Could it be that the required files are timing out?